# Depth first search in Satstuma Graph

Tags: c#, .net, graph, depth-first-search

Is there any easy way to do **depth first search** on graph using **Satsuma Graph** in .NET? In the Satsuma documentation i have found that clas DFS is abstract, so it cant have any instances and i dont know how to use it.

[satsuma.dfs documentation](http://satsumagraph.sourceforge.net/doc/html/class_satsuma_1_1_dfs.html)

do i have to make my own class for DFS which inherits from satsuma.dfs? I didnt find any examples of using satsuma.dfs class.

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class which inherits from abstract Sutsama DFS and then you can create an instance of this class and call void Run (IGraph graph, IEnumerable roots=null) method using it to search.
Optionally you can override virtual methods of the abstract class to customize the search algorithm.